# Error trying to add a view to a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to use an AsyncTask to receive some information from a remote database and use it to generate a dinamyc list in the screen. First, I execute the AsyncTask and when it finishes I call a method of my Activity to change the screen, but it generates an error I can't fix.

This is the code of my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button but;
ArrayList<String> array;
ArrayList<String> array2;
JSONArray players = null;
RelativeLayout rl;


@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final String  s= intent.getStringExtra("firstKeyName");



    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.marco);




         Hilo hilo = new Hilo(this, s);
         hilo.execute();




      }

protected void pantalla(final JSONArray players){


     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
      DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

      final Integer h= metrics.heightPixels;
      final Integer w= metrics.widthPixels;


      Button b1 = new Button(this);
      params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (w*0.8), (int) (h*0.16));
      params.leftMargin = (int) (0);
      params.topMargin = (int) (h*0.5);

     rl.addView(b1,params);

}
}
```

I think the code of my method onCreate is not necesary.
And this is the code of the AsyncTask

```
public class Hilo extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Void> {

private MainActivity activity2;
 JSONArray players = null;
 String s;

    public Hilo(MainActivity activity, String s2)
    {
        activity2 = activity;
        s=s2;
    }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //players = new JSONArray();

      if(hay_internet()){

          RestClient client = null;



         client = new RestClient("myurl");


           try {
               client.Execute(RestClient.RequestMethod.GET);
           } catch (Exception e) {

           }

           String response = client.getResponse();

           try {

             JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(response);
           players = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("questions"));




              } catch (Exception e) {

                }


      }
           activity2.pantalla(players);
        return null;


}

public boolean hay_internet(){

    RestClient client = new RestClient("myurl");

    Integer i=0;
       try {
           client.Execute(RestClient.RequestMethod.GET);
       } catch (Exception e) {

       }

       String response = client.getResponse();

       try {

         JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(response);
         JSONArray players = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("questions"));

          i=players.getJSONObject(0).getString("Jugador").toString().length();


          } catch (Exception e) {

            }

       return (i==7);
    }







}
```

The method hay_internet() is only to verify there is Internet Connection.

The error appears when I try to add a view in the method pantalla() using a RelativeLayout that is a global variable I have initalized in the method onStart().

Comment: Formatting you code well does NOT hurt. Please do so as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to call `setContentView` method before referencing `RelativeLayout`. Override `onCreate` method and call it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.<YourXmlContainingRelativelayout>);
}
```

**[Update]**
The culprit is this call:

```
activity2.pantalla(players);
```

Override `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask` and call it from there. The reason being android does not allow you to do UI related stuffs in background thread. You must do **UI related stuffs** in main thread.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object arg0) {
    //do something after background execution is complete
    //Executes on main thread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not update/add view in AsynkTask method (i.e. any background thread/method) 
You have to do it on UI thread. AsynkTask's onPostExecute() executes on UI thread, so call you r method in onPostExecute().

Also use

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(layoutfilename);
 }
```

Comment: I have done the setContentView in my onCreate(), the problem is that I want to set the view in the method pantalla(). How can I do that?

Comment: That's what I said, call pantalla(players); this method in onPostExecute() methos of AsyncTask. Do not call it in doInBackground.

Comment: I have done it and the error isn't fixed. I think the problem is that I am trying to add a view from a method it isn't onCreate(), onStart(), etc.